# Redirect entire site to https

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my entire site, including all subdomains to https.

Will this work?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you test it from your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code may work alright but I would recommend using `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`. Please understand the difference between 2 variables. `%{SERVER_NAME}` is the name of the server as configured in your Apache config but later one is the domain name received in real time in HTTP request. So instead of your code use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**In order to exclude above rule for a particular sub-domain use something like this code:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work.

The important thing is to make sure that rule is **before** any routing rules you may have and that no other rules redirect to `http://`.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted redirect the entire site except one subdomain, how would I go about that?